# Number of columns mismatch in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-algorithms

So I have the following code

`qgan = QGAN(real_data, bounds, num_qubits, batch_size, num_epochs, snapshot_dir=None)`

with num qubits being defined as

`num_qubits = [2, 2]`

but it is outputting the following error on the qgan line:

`operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,) (2,)`

I suspect this is due to the fact that it is currently configured to handle a 2 dimensional data set with two columns but I am attempting to feed a 2 dimensional data set with 9 columns. How do I allow the qgan to support 9 columns?

Comment: Hello, could you specify which language this is in?

Comment: Yeah this is in python. I am actually using the IBM Qsikit library